# Simple logic statement in PowerShell using WMI

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

In PowerShell, I'm typing the statement:

```
$var = Get-WmiObject win32_product | select-object name

if ($var.name -like 'adobe') {write-host '123'}
```

The variable stores the list of installed products just fine; however, my `if` then won't catch anything. On execution I get no output or error. This works if I use something like [Get-Process](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849832.aspx), but not with [Get-WmiObject](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849824.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-like` operator is a wildcard pattern matching operator. It returns things that match the expression you provide. Use `*` as the wildcard character. So you would use:

```
if ($var.name -like '*adobe*') {write-host '123'}
```

**Update** - Accessing the name property on the collection like this only worked for me in PowerShell v3. For PowerShell v2 I think you'll need to do things a little differently. I'd suggest creating a string array instead of a collection of PsCustomObjects like this (the `-ExpandProperty` param does the work):

```
$var = get-wmiobject win32_product | ? {$_.Name} | select-object -Expand name
```

Then do the if statement without using the name property:

```
if ($var -like '*adobe*') {write-host '123'}
```

If you have something installed with adobe in the name it will execute the IF block.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer is that it's better to ask WMI to filter on the server, and you'll have less network traffic. Here is an example with a WMI filter:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_Product -Filter "name like '%adobe%'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I never realized there was a -like comparison operator?  I usually use .Contains("value looking for") in that instance.

However, just noticed here that there is a -contains operator.

[Mastering PowerShell, Chapter 7 Conditions](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebook/archive/2009/03/08/chapter-7-conditions.aspx)

Ah, if you getting more than one result back you will need to loop through them:

```
$var | foreach-object { if ( $_.name -contains 'adobe' ) { write-host '123' } }
```

Something like that maybe?

$var is the results list, which doesn't have a property 'name', but each item in the list should.

Comment: I'm not getting any results/output/errors back unfortunately. I tried your suggestion but am getting the same result. Maybe it's the way the WMI object is stored? when outputting the variable after it's stored it looks okay.

Comment: That makes it a tougher nut :)  Have you tried comparing $var -eq $null?  or even piping $var | gm  to see what properties on it.  You can also call $var.GetType() to see what type of object it is.  Don't know if any of that helps?

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Zach's answer, the like operator as you've stated it:

```
$var.name -like 'adobe'
```

will only match if if he name isexactly  equal to 'abobe'.

For e.g.

```
PS C:\> 'adobe' -like 'adobe'
True
PS C:\> 'Adobe Air' -like 'adobe'
False
```

However, -like is intended to be used with wildcards:

```
PS C:\> 'Adobe Air' -like '*adobe*'
True
```

and so you can do

```
$var | foreach{ if ( $_.name -like '*adobe*' ) { write-host '123' } }
```

or, in the more POSH style, use where-object

```
$var | where-object{ $_.name -like '*adobe*' } |  write-host '123'
```

Answer (score 0):

`$var.name` only works when `$var` contains a single object (scalar, singelton). When `$var` holds a collection of items, PowerShell tries to get you the Name property of the collection itself.

The collection/array doesn't have a Name property and you get nothing back. That said, `$var.Name` will work in PowerShell v3.

To compare to the Name property you need to loop through all objects and:

```
if ($var.name -like 'adobe') {write-host '123'}
```

If you'd extracted all values (`$var` contains a list of strings) then you could do:

```
$var = get-wmiobject win32_product | select-object -expand name

if ($var -like 'adobe') {write-host '123'}
```

Comment: I don't think I like it working in PsV3... That's an odd feature that will make PsV2/PsV3 scripts incompatible.

Comment: This is a price I am gladly willing to pay. Don't forget that you can launch PowerShell - version 2. Think of an XML where you need to parse each node that has several child objects many levels deep down: $xml|%{$_.one}|%{$_.two}|%{$_.three} and so on, when now you can simply do: $xml.one.two.three and PowerShell will do (what I like to call) "implicit foreach" on each root node.

Comment: I usually use xpath to process xml. I find it easier to use than the noteproperties but good point about the launching the 2.0 engine from verion 3.